# Encapsulation for mutable objects in Java

Tags: java, immutability, encapsulation, mutable

I was studying the "Java SE 7 Programmer I & II Study Guide" and I did not understand the explanation below.

```
class Fortress{
  private String name;
  private ArrayList<Integer> list;

  Fortress（） {list=new ArrayList<Integer>;

  String getName{return name;}
  void addToList(int x){list.add(x);}
  ArrayList getList(){return list;} // line 1
}
```

Which lines of code break encapsulation? Answer: line 9. "When encapsulating a mutable object like an ArrayList, your getter must return a reference to a copy of the object, not just the reference to the original object".

I did not either understand the explanation or how to modifiy the original code.

So in the getList() instead of

```
return list;
```

Should we do this?

```
ArrayList<Integer> list2=list;
return list2;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would have replace:

```
return list;
```

with:

```
return new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
```

Otherwise the client can do...

```
foo.getList().add(5);
```

breaking encapsulation.

Answer (score 2):

```
we do this?

ArrayList<Integer> list2=list;
return list2;
```

No, it says a copy of the object, not a copy of the reference.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list2= new ArrayList<>();
list2.addAll( list );
return list2;
```

Or as pointed out, `ArrayList` has a copy constructor that will add all elements from another list to the new list.  The above three lines are intended primarily to be clear what is being done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the copy constructor

```
return new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return list;
```

would return the reference to your **private ArrayList list** this is where the encapsulation breaks.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list2=list;
return list2;
```

Even here also you are simply passing the reference of your **list** to **list2** You can try -

```
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.addAll(list);
```